# SortDictionary but sort by Value

Tags: .net, sorting

How do you SortDictionary by value (.NET 2.0)? Or is there any alternative to this?

I am trying to sort Tags just like in blogger. But I want to sort the Tags by number there were used, not by name?

---

I have to ask again .. 
why this code wont work when used in ASP.NET

```
result.Sort((first, second) => second.Value.CompareTo(first.Value));
```

it throws 5 errors while building

Comment: I'm trying to determine if the `KeyedCollection` will do what you want. It is an abstract hybrid between the IList and IDictionary. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lambda function and a List to do something like:

```
var myList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(myList);
result.Sort((first, second) => second.Value.CompareTo(first.Value));
```

Comment: +1 This method will also allow you to provide different sorting options by just using an alternate lambda function.